# The method map((<no type> cfg) -> {}) is undefined for the type List<capture#1-of ? extends Config>

Tags: java, lambda

I am afraid this is the matter of simple lambda map function. But I have no idea how. Below is my java codes,

```
public SparkConf createSparkConf(String appName, Config config) {
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster(config.getString("system.master")).setAppName(appName);

    config.getConfigList("spark").map(cfg -> {
        String name = "spark." + cfg.getString("name");
        String value = cfg.getString("value");
        sparkConf.set(name, value);
    });

    if(config.hasPath("app")) {
        config.getConfigList("app").map(cfg -> {
            String name = "spark." + cfg.getString("name");
            String value = cfg.getString("value");
            sparkConf.set(name, value);
        });
    }

    return sparkConf;
}
```

But the map function throws the following exception.

```
The method map((<no type> cfg) -> {}) is undefined for the type List<capture#1-of ? extends Config>
```

`config.getConfigList("app")` line returns `List<Config>`, but I have no idea why map function throws such errors. Any idea?

Comment: a `List` has no `map` method. A `Stream` has `map` method. That said, if you wanted to use `Stream`'s `map`, the mapping function passed to it should return something.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `forEach` method, since you're not collecting the results of the `map` operation. Also you can call `list.stream().map(...)` to reach it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have one more question. What statement should be inserted into forEach function? I convert this codes from Scala codes. And I can not find forEach function

Comment: The features you're asking for are available starting from JDK 8. If you can't find it, perhaps you're using java 7 or older?